# How to use normalising gel, cleansing milk, toner and protein mask

Tags: dermatology, topical-cream-gel, face, cosmetics

I have been using normalising gel to wash my face. I got as a present cleansing milk, toner and protein mask. How am I supposed to use these?

I kind of understand that toner is used to remove those other products but which? What I have found is that it should be used to neutralise some drying chemicals in tap water like chlorine.

What is the relationship with normalising gel and cleansing milk? Is their functionality the same? I have not found any source where the two would be used.

Also, in which point should I use that protein mask? Is it something that is to be cleaned off?

Not sure if this belong to health but skin care is closest to health of the existing stacks.